# Left Join vs line query with execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am still learning reading execution plan in SQL Server. I was wondering if someone can please advise me on which of the following query is faster.

**Left join:**

```
SELECT  
    [InvoiceNum] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),H.Date, 101) + ' #'
    + RTRIM(SUBSTRING(RptText, CHARINDEX('No.', RptText) + 3, 25))
FROM    
    dbo.RptDisplayHeader H
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.RptDisplayDetail d ON d.RptID =H.RptID
                           AND d.ID =H.ID
                           AND d.Date =H.Date
                           AND d.Seq = 2
WHERE   
   H.ID = @ID
    ANDH.RptID = @RptID
ORDER BY 
   H.Date DESC;
```

**Inline query:**

```
SELECT  
    [InvoiceNum] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),H.Date, 101)
    + (SELECT 
           ' #' + RTRIM(SUBSTRING(RptText, CHARINDEX('No.', RptText) + 3, 25))
       FROM    
           dbo.RptDisplayDetail d
       WHERE   
           d.ID = @ID
           AND d.RptID = @RptID
           AND d.Seq = 2
           AND d.Date =H.Date)
 FROM    
     dbo.RptDisplayHeaderH 
 WHERE   
    H.ID = @ID
     ANDH.RptID = @RptID
 ORDER BY 
    H.Date DESC;
```

Execution plan:

[image]

Inline statistics:

```
  Table 'RptDisplayDetail'. Scan count 1723, logical reads 5444, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
  Table 'RptDisplayHeader'. Scan count 1, logical reads 58, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Left join statistics:

```
  Table 'RptDisplayDetail'. Scan count 1723, logical reads 5792, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
  Table 'RptDisplayHeader'. Scan count 1, logical reads 58, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Comment: The queries are not logically the same without an assumption. Is that a safe assumption? Do you see the assumption?

Comment: @SMor Why they are not logically same?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the Estimated Sub Tree cost of the left most select statement (which is the last operation executed)

The one with the lowest cost is (in theory) your fastest query.

A more reliable measure is the IO statistics you have posted.

Based on your statistics you have posted, the inline query is marginally better as there are less logical reads on the table RptDisplayDetail. However, personally, I would do away with that marginal gain in favour of the readability of the other query (unless you are specifically having performance issues)

There is [a great video over at BrentOzar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/sql/watch-brent-tune-queries/) where he tunes an example query on the StackOverflow Database

Comment: Thanks, i have added stats info in my question :) LEFT JOIN has more logical reads.